# write arabic in Excel sheet by delphi?

Tags: delphi, excel, unicode, delphi-7

I want to write Arabic text in an Excel Sheet by using Delphi. When I write on the sheet I get something like this ÌÇÝÇ. 
Also, how can I change the excel data type from Delphi code?

Comment: Which Excel do you have? 2003, 2007 or 2010? Just to make that sure: the excel you have has arabic as menu language? Then you would need to get known to the api to deliver right formatted letters (unicode or something else)

Comment: i use excel 2007 but how can make format letters or unicode

Comment: Can you show an example of code?

Comment: what is the data that you are trying to store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. open the Control Panel.
2. double-click Regional and Language Options.
3. in "Standard and Format", select "Arab Algeria."
4. down in "location", select "Algeria".
5. in "Languages" tab, check "Install files for complex script and languages ​​written from right to left" and also tick "Install files for East Asian languages​​".
6. Now go to the tab "Advanced" and select "Arab Algeria."
7. restart your PC and voila. (Rest of us to you to confirm)

Comment: how can I change the excel data type from Delphi code?